# WPF treeview checkboxes, how to check all children when parent is checked

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, treeview, parent-child

Yes, i know its been asked a bazillion times, I've looked through, and tried most of those answers. for context, I'm creating a dock-able pane within an API (Revit). Most solutions are based on the Windows class, but I'm forced to use a Page class for the form. My data is gathered from two lists parsed through a custom class and sorted into one list, then i had the brilliant idea of mapping it to a dictionary, with one of the list properties as its key. Displaying the dictionary in a treeview was nice an easy, but as you can see checking the Parent does not check all its children:
[image: Populated TreeView]

So id like to keep the dictionary if possible, but am fully prepared to restructure my list as needed to get this working.
To summarize the ask:

- Keep the data structured as as a Dictionory if possible.
- Be able to check all children when parent is checked, but parent should not be checked (i do not require a three state) when children are checked.
- Checkbox and item are separate controls, such that user can select an item, which will display and image without checking the checkbox.

What i've tried; recursive functions and Revit do not mix, so mapping my list to the treeview that way is out. Binding the IsChecked of the child to the parent and vice versa. I think this fails due to the way the xaml is structured to use the dictionary. And a slew of other things i cant think of right now.

Anyways, heres the XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="Typ_Detail_Selector.TypDetForm"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Title="Typical Detail Selector" Foreground="{x:Null}" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="400" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label Content="Views" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TreeView x:Name="TreeViewDets" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" MinWidth="400" SelectedItemChanged="TreeViewDets_SelectedItemChanged">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" Click="CheckPleaseParent"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" Click="CheckPleaseChild"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType = "TreeViewItem">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Loaded}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DimGray"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Loaded}" Value="false"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Checked}" Value="true"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SteelBlue"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Azure"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Loaded}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DimGray"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Resources>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="RunButton" Content="Insert Views" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="180" Height="25" Click="Run_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

And the xaml.cs, i must stress this is for API work, so theres a lot of extra things not specific to the WPF itself:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events;
using View = Autodesk.Revit.DB.View;
using Application = Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application;
using Transform = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transform;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;

namespace Typ_Detail_Selector
{
    public partial class TypDetForm : Page, IDockablePaneProvider
    {
        private TypDetailRegister TypDetViews;
        public Document TypDoc;
        private Document ThisDoc;
        private Application App;
        private UIApplication UiApp;
        private Dictionary<string, List<ViewProperties>> viewDict = new Dictionary<string, List<ViewProperties>>();

        public TypDetForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void SetupDockablePane(DockablePaneProviderData data)
        {
            data.FrameworkElement = this;
            data.InitialState = new DockablePaneState();
            data.InitialState.DockPosition = DockPosition.Right;
        }
        public void ReferenceItems(TypDetailRegister _typdetviews, Document _typdoc, Document _thisdoc, Application _app)
        {   //this is to set references to things from command class
            TypDoc = _typdoc;
            ThisDoc = _thisdoc;
            TypDetViews = _typdetviews;
            App = _app;
            UiApp = new UIApplication(App);
            UiApp.Idling += TypDetViews.TwiddleThumbs;
            viewDict = TypDetViews.ViewList().GroupBy(x => x.SheetName).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
            RefreshCompare();
        }
        public void RefreshCompare()
        {//compares list of views an schedules in the current project to the typ det file,
         //flags them as "loaded" so you cant re import them later.
            List<ViewProperties> _tempviewprops = TypDetViews.ViewList();
            List<Element> _compareViewList = new FilteredElementCollector(ThisDoc).OfClass(typeof(ViewDrafting))
                .Where(v => v.Name != "MKA Starting View").ToList();
            List<Element> _compareSchedList = new FilteredElementCollector(ThisDoc).OfClass(typeof(ViewSchedule))
                .Where(s => !s.Name.ToUpper().Contains("REVISION"))
                .Where(s => !s.Name.Contains("DRAWING LIST"))
                .ToList();
            _compareViewList.AddRange(_compareSchedList);
            foreach (ViewProperties v in TypDetViews.ViewList())
            {
                var _viewExists = from views in _compareViewList
                                  where v.Name == views.Name
                                  select v;
                if (_viewExists.Any())
                {
                    v.Loaded = true;
                    v.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    v.Loaded = false;
                    v.Checked = false;
                }
            }

            TreeViewDets.ItemsSource = null;
            TreeViewDets.ItemsSource = viewDict;
        }
      
        private void ListViewDets_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {   //handler for when user selects (but not checks!) and item in teh list
            string imagelibrary = @"K:\Development\_Typical Detail Change Tracking\Base Models\Typ Images";
            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0) //check if something was in fact selected
            {
                //dim teh item as a member of the list class to get at certain properites
                ViewProperties test = e.AddedItems[0] as ViewProperties;
                try
                {
                    //replace characters that windows automatically replaces for the png files
                    string view_image = imagelibrary + "\\" + test.Name.Replace("\"", "-").Replace("/", "-") + ".png";
                    if (File.Exists(view_image))//if an image file exists in teh library
                    { //add it to to image control on the form as preview.
                        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(view_image, UriKind.Absolute));
                        // PreviewImage.Source = bmp;
                    }
                }
                catch { }
                e.AddedItems.Clear();//clear it so program does not get confused the next time handler is triggered.
            }
        }

        private void CheckPleaseChild(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { //seperate handler to change the checkbox, and ping the selection changed event
            var cb = sender as CheckBox;
            var item = cb.DataContext;
            ListViewDets.SelectedItem = item;
        }
        private void CheckPleaseParent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { //seperate handler to change the checkbox, and ping the selection changed event
            var cb = sender as CheckBox;
            var iteam = cb.DataContext;
            PropertyInfo[] testprops = cb.DataContext.GetType().GetProperties();
            List<ViewProperties> testlist = new List<ViewProperties>();
            testlist = (List<ViewProperties>)testprops.Last().GetValue(cb.DataContext, null);
            foreach (var temp in testlist)
            {
                //need to trigger checkpleasechild somehow?

            }

        }
        private void TreeViewDets_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            TreeView tv = sender as TreeView;
            var item = tv.Items.CurrentItem; //this gets me the KVP, same as in checkpleaseparent
        }
        private void ListViewDets_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {   //this is to stretch the listview with the form
            ListView tempview = sender as ListView;
            GridView gview = tempview.View as GridView;
            var defaultwidth = tempview.ActualWidth - SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
            var percent = 0.95;
            gview.Columns[1].Width = defaultwidth * percent;
        }
        private void Run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   //clicking run, sets the bool, which in trun runs the InsertViews when able (idling)
            GlobalVars.DoTheThings = true;
        }
        public void InsertViews(ExternalCommandData commdata)
        {
            GlobalVars.DoTheThings = false;//reset bool
            App.FailuresProcessing += HideDupeMessages;//to deal with dupilcate names dialog
            ExternalCommandData _commdata = commdata;
            //grab all the element ids of items that are checked in the list, but not loaded, which are the views we want to insert
            ICollection<ElementId> _viewIds = TypDetViews.ViewList().Where(x => x.Checked && !x.Loaded).Select(y => y.ViewId).ToList();
            ICollection<ElementId> _copiedViewIds = null;
            Document _doc = _commdata.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
            ThisDoc = _doc;
            using (TransactionGroup tg = new TransactionGroup(_doc)) //trans group to keep the undo list clean
            {
                tg.Start();
                using (Transaction trView = new Transaction(_doc))
                {
                    foreach (ElementId _viewId in _viewIds)
                    {
                        ICollection<ElementId> _vId = _viewIds.Where(x => x == _viewId).ToList(); //annoying API thing, must put the element id in an Icollection, else it doesn work
                        bool test = TypDetViews.ViewList().Where(x => x.ViewId == _vId.First()).Select(y => y.SchedTest).First();//is it a scehdule?
                        trView.Start("Copy Typ Views to Project");
                        {
                            CopyPasteOptions opts = new CopyPasteOptions();
                            opts.SetDuplicateTypeNamesHandler(new DupeNamesHandler());
                            try
                            {   //add the elementid of the view or sched that was just inserted to a empty collection
                                _copiedViewIds = ElementTransformUtils.CopyElements(TypDoc, _vId, _doc, Transform.Identity, opts);
                            }
                            catch { }
                            trView.Commit();
                        }
                        //if its not a sched, grab every element in teh view,
                        //bypass for scheds, as it grabs the modeled elements in the sched(errors out for stickies)
                        if (test)
                        {
                            ICollection<ElementId> _nestedEelemIds = new FilteredElementCollector(TypDoc, _viewId)
                                .WherePasses(new ElementCategoryFilter(ElementId.InvalidElementId, true))
                                .ToElementIds();
                            //if we foudn elements, copy them from the typ view to the new view we just inserted
                            if (_nestedEelemIds.Count > 0)
                            {
                                View _sourceView = TypDoc.GetElement(_viewId) as View;
                                View _targetView = _doc.GetElement(_copiedViewIds.First()) as View;
                                using (Transaction trElements = new Transaction(_doc))
                                {
                                    trElements.Start("Copy Typ Det Elements to Project View");
                                    CopyPasteOptions opts = new CopyPasteOptions();
                                    opts.SetDuplicateTypeNamesHandler(new DupeNamesHandler());
                                    ElementTransformUtils.CopyElements(_sourceView, _nestedEelemIds, _targetView, Transform.Identity, opts);
                                    trElements.Commit();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        _copiedViewIds.Clear();//clear teh list for the next run.
                    }
                }
                tg.Assimilate();
            }

            //write to a text file
            try
            {
                string log_file = "Typical Detail Selector.txt";
                string text = "";
                string date = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
                string user = Environment.UserName;
                string other = "Run";
                text = date + " ~ " + user + " ~ " + other;
                StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("J:/CADD/Customization/Add-In Usage/" + log_file);
                sw.WriteLine(text);
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            RefreshCompare();//refresh the lsit when we done inserting views.
        }
        public void SetActiveDocument()
        {
            ThisDoc = UiApp.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
            RefreshCompare();
        }
        public void NewDocCity(object sender, DocumentOpenedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetActiveDocument();
        }
       
        //public PreviewControl PrevCon { get; set; }
        private void HideDupeMessages(object sender, FailuresProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            FailuresAccessor FA = e.GetFailuresAccessor();
            foreach (FailureMessageAccessor fmsg in FA.GetFailureMessages())
            {
                if (fmsg.GetSeverity() == FailureSeverity.Warning)
                {
                    FA.DeleteWarning(fmsg);
                    e.SetProcessingResult(FailureProcessingResult.ProceedWithCommit);
                }
            }
            e.SetProcessingResult(FailureProcessingResult.Continue);
        }
    }
    public class DupeNamesHandler : IDuplicateTypeNamesHandler
    {
        public DuplicateTypeAction OnDuplicateTypeNamesFound(DuplicateTypeNamesHandlerArgs args)
        {
            return DuplicateTypeAction.UseDestinationTypes;
        }
    }
}
```

Edited to include ViewProperties.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;

namespace Typ_Detail_Selector
{
    public class ViewProperties
    {
        private Document _typdoc;
        TypDetailRegister _typdetcomm;
        public ViewProperties(TypDetailRegister typdetcomm, Document TypDoc, Element _elem, bool test)
        {
            _typdoc = TypDoc;
            Checked = false;
            Loaded = false;
            SchedTest = test;
            _typdetcomm = typdetcomm;
            Regex numReg = new Regex(@"[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*");//matches numbers 1.8, .3, 4
            SortNum = 0;
            MatchCollection matchnum;
            if (test) //for drating views.
            {
                SortNumDec = 0;
                TypView = _elem as View;
                Name = TypView.Name;//view name
                SheetName = TypView.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.VIEWPORT_SHEET_NUMBER).AsString();//sheet number its on
                ViewId = TypView.Id; //elementid, needed to insert the view later
                matchnum = numReg.Matches(Name); //looking for numbers in teh view name for sorting
                ViewSheet vs = new FilteredElementCollector(_typdoc) //the sheet object that the view is on.
                    .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Sheets)
                    .Where(x => x.LookupParameter("Sheet Number").AsString() == SheetName)
                    .FirstOrDefault() as ViewSheet;
                if (matchnum.Count == 1)//if we have one match
                {
                    SortNum = Convert.ToInt32(matchnum[0].Value); //ex.1
                }
                else if (matchnum.Count >= 2)
                {
                    SortNum = Convert.ToInt32(matchnum[0].Value + matchnum[1].Value);// ex 11
                }
                string seriessort = vs.LookupParameter("S_SheetSort_SheetSeriesNumber").AsString();
                string subsort = vs.LookupParameter("S_SheetSort_SheetSeriesSubNumber").AsString();
                MatchCollection matchsort = numReg.Matches(seriessort);//grab teh numerical value in teh series sort parameter
                MatchCollection matchsubsort = numReg.Matches(subsort);//grab the numerical value in teh series sub sort parameter
                SheetSort = Convert.ToInt32(matchsort[0].Value);
                SubSort = Convert.ToInt32(matchsubsort[0].Value);
            }
            else //for schedules
            {
                SortNumDec = 1;// alwasy set to 1 so it show up after its view, as much as possible
                ScheduleSheetInstance _sched = (ScheduleSheetInstance)_elem; //the instance of teh schedule on sheet
                TypView = _typdoc.GetElement(_sched.ScheduleId) as View; //the schedule source (whats in the project browser)
                Name = _sched.Name;
                SheetName = _typdoc.GetElement(_sched.OwnerViewId).LookupParameter("Sheet Number").AsString();//sheet number its on
                ViewId = _sched.ScheduleId; //elementid of schedule source, for inserting
                matchnum = numReg.Matches(Name);//looking for numbers in teh schedule name for sorting, ex. BF1_Brace Frame Schedule
                if (matchnum.Count > 0 && !Name.EndsWith(matchnum[matchnum.Count - 1].Value))//if we have some number of matches, and name does not end with a match.
                {
                    if (matchnum.Count == 1)
                    {
                        SortNum = Convert.ToInt32(matchnum[0].Value);
                    }
                    else if (matchnum.Count == 2)
                    {
                        SortNum = Convert.ToInt32(matchnum[0].Value + matchnum[1].Value);
                    }
                    else if (_typdetcomm.ViewList().Any(x => x.Name.Equals(Name)))
                    {
                        SortNum = _typdetcomm.ViewList().Where(x => x.Name == Name).Select(y => y.SortNum).First();
                    }
                }
                else //if no number matches in teh sched name
                {
                    //split up the sched name, and do partial matches to view names
                    var viewnames = _typdetcomm.ViewList().Where(x => x.SheetName == SheetName).Select(y => new { y.Name, y.SortNum });
                    var namesplit = Name.Split(null);
                    string namepattern = @"\b" + string.Join("|", namesplit.Select(w => Regex.Escape(w))) + @"\b";
                    Regex wordreg = new Regex(namepattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    List<int> _sortnum = new List<int>();
                    foreach (var pair in viewnames)
                    {
                        string name = pair.Name;
                        var matches = Regex.Matches(name, namepattern).OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value).Distinct();
                        if (matches.Count() >= 2) //greater or equal to 2 matches, its probably teh one we want
                        {
                            _sortnum.Add(_typdetcomm.ViewList().Where(x => x.Name == name).Select(y => y.SortNum).First());
                        }
                        if (_sortnum.Count >= 1)//one or more, cant really tell, but put it to the last valid match.
                        {
                            SortNum = _sortnum.Max();
                        }
                    }
                    if (_sortnum.Count == 0)//no matches...um i forget what this does, but finds the best match
                    {
                        SortNum = viewnames.Aggregate((x, y) => x.SortNum > y.SortNum ? x : y).SortNum;
                    }
                    _sortnum.Clear();
                }
                ViewSheet vs = _typdoc.GetElement(_sched.OwnerViewId) as ViewSheet;
                string seriessort = vs.LookupParameter("S_SheetSort_SheetSeriesNumber").AsString();
                string subsort = vs.LookupParameter("S_SheetSort_SheetSeriesSubNumber").AsString();
                MatchCollection matchsort = numReg.Matches(seriessort);
                MatchCollection matchsubsort = numReg.Matches(subsort);
                SheetSort = Convert.ToInt32(matchsort[0].Value);
                SubSort = Convert.ToInt32(matchsubsort[0].Value);

            }
        }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
        public bool Loaded { get; set; }
        public bool SchedTest { get; set; }
        public int SortNum { get; set; }
        public int SortNumDec { get; set; }
        public int SheetSort { get; set; }
        public int SubSort { get; set; }
        public View TypView { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SheetName { get; set; }
        public ElementId ViewId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the `Checked` property of all children that belong to a parent node for example by using recursion:

**ExamplTreeDataItem.cs**

```cs
class ExamplTreeDataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // TODO::Initialize from constructor
  public ObservableCollection<ExamplTreeDataItem> Children { get; }

  private bool isSelected;

  // Binds to CheckBox
  public bool IsSelected 
  { 
    get => this.isSelected;
    set 
    {
      this.isSelected = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnIsSelectedChanged();
    }
  }

  private void OnIsSelectedChanged()
  {
    foreach (ExamplTreeDataItem child in this.Children)
    {
      // Select or unselect child (follow parent)
      child.IsSelected = this.IsSelected;
    }
  }
}
```

It's recommended to apply such operations on the data model. It's easier than handling view elements (for example by handling UI events like `CheckBox.Click`).
In the above example the `IsSelected` property value will change (for example when the `IsSelected` property is bound to a e.g. `CheckBox`)  and the property setter will set all child item `IsSelected` accordingly. This triggers a recursive action as each child will on its own set the `IsSelected` property of its own child items.

Comment: I do not believe this will work for me, first how would i even implement this with the rest of my code? Second as stated, recursive functions are not my friend, and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: *"first how would i even implement this with the rest of my code?"* - Good question, because you never provided any details about your data structure. My example shows a usual tree data structure where each node can have child nodes. The principle applies to every tree structure: walk down the tree starting from the current parent and set a dedicated property that marks an item as selected. The key is to work on the data structure and not on the UI elements.

Comment: *"Second as stated, recursive functions are not my friend, and should be avoided if possible."* - You have never stated anything like this. However, it doesn't make sense either. What do you think tree node expanding in the TreeView is implemented? Tree traversal is always implemented recursive or iterative. You can easily convert a recursive algorithm to an iterative equivalent. You can further improve the algorithm by limiting it to a particular tree depth, for example only select the children of the next level and wait for the user to expand the second child level before selecting them.

Comment: *"recursive functions  [...] should be avoided if possible"* - This is a very broad statement that is nonsense. There are edge cases where recursion can become expensive. This is not such an edge case.

Comment: In your code your data items appear to have a `Checked` property that you bind to the `CheckBox`. Simply replace the `IsSelecetd` in my example with your `Checked` property. And my `Children` collection could be your `Value` collection.

Comment: i thought i had given details of my data structure in the code? its a 'Dictionary<string, List<ViewProperties>>' being mapped from a 'List<ViewProperties>>' with the key being a property in said List.

Comment: Sorry, I just had the feeling you were not showing the tree structure itself, like the ViewProperties class. You only showed the source collection. But maybe I'm wrong and I was just not reading carefully enough..

Comment: a fair point, original edited to include ViewProperties.cs